# Text compression

Tags: random, compression, lz4

If we use less unique elements like (a-z) instead  of (A-z) do the families  of LZ algorithms efficiency increase?

Is there any  other compression algorithm efficient for random unique elements at present?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, efficiency increases (on average) because there will be more and longer matches. Also, Huffman-style compression becomes stronger.

> Is there any other compression algorithm efficient for random unique elements at present ?

Not sure what you mean. If you mean that individual characters are independent then even basic compression algorithms will achieve theoretically optimal efficiency.

Comment: My question is " In compression text file which contains only numbers  for example (0-9) , now currently 
which  compression algorithm  is best ? "
Thankyou

Comment: Depends on what kinds of patterns there are in that file. I think you should Google for the most common algorithms and get a basic understanding for how they work.